# How to add pagination to slivet list

Tags: flutter

```
     CustomScrollView(
                 // controller: con,
                controller: _controller,
               slivers: [
                 SliverPersistentHeader(
                   delegate: HomeScreenCustomSliverAppBar(
                       expandedHeight: height / 2),
                   pinned: true,
                 ),
                 SliverToBoxAdapter(
                   child: Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 25, 10, 20),
                     child: Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           FontAwesomeIcons.globeAmericas,
                           size: 20,
                           color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                         ),
                         SizedBox(
                           width: 8,
                         ),
                         Text(
                           Applocalizations.of(context).translate("Explore"),
                           style: textStyleSemiBold().copyWith(
                               fontSize: 25, color: Colors.black87),
                         ),
                         Divider(),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),


              SliverList(
                     delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                   (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     return GestureDetector(
                       onTap: () {
                         print('taaaaaaped '+ index.toString());
                       //  var list = bestDeals[index];
                       //  print("testing the list : "+list.toString());
                         Navigator.push(
                             context,
                             MaterialPageRoute(
                                 builder: (context) => PropertyPage(
                                   property: allPropertiesProvider.allProperties[index],
                                     )));
                       },
                       child: Container(
                         child: DealsCard(propertyData: allPropertiesProvider.allProperties[index],),
                       ),
                     );
                   },
                   childCount: allPropertiesProvider.allProperties.length,
                 ))
               ],
             ),
```